# Trouble using .change to verify answer

Tags: javascript, input

I'm having some trouble using a .change on a text input field. It's supposed to use a library (artisan), if said answer is right (in this case equal to 1), to draw text on a canvas but it's not doing so.

Here's the javascript

```
$('#atomnum').change(function(){
        ans = $('#atomnum').val();
    });

    if(ans == 1){
        artisan.drawText('canvas', 200, 300, 'Correto!', '#FFFFFF');
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

The input's id is atomnum. Any help?

Edit - Tried bot of those, still not working. [Here](https://gist.github.com/1918499)'s the whole function that gets called, maybe that çistener shouldn't be inside that function...

Comment: Why do you have a stray closing-brace (`}`) at the end of your code sample? And I think your `if`/`else` should be inside the `change()`.

Answer (score 0):

If the drawing action is supposed to happen inside the `.change()` event, put it inside:

```
$('#atomnum').change(function(){
    ans = $('#atomnum').val();
    if(ans == 1){
        artisan.drawText('canvas', 200, 300, 'Correto!', '#FFFFFF');
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Otherwise, you would have needed an additional function to check the new value of `ans` and act on it accordingly.

Note - removed an extra closing `}`

Answer (score 0):

That code cannot work. You execute the checking code right after binding the event a single time instead of running it whenever the element changes.

Try this instead:

```
$('#atomnum').change(function(e) {
    var ans = $('#atomnum').val();

    if(ans == '1') {
        artisan.drawText('canvas', 200, 300, 'Correto!', '#FFFFFF');
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: This only works if I click outside the canvas after inputing the number... Strange...

Comment: That's how the `change` event works for text fields - as soon as it loses focus, the event fires if the value has been changed. If you don't want this, you need to use both `keyup` and `change` (to ensure it always triggers, even after pasting via the context menu).

Comment: Is using keyup the same as change, except you don't need to focus somewhere else?